# Invalid argument to function in access sql WHERE NOT IN

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table1

```
  PreA  BaB   CPS  CommName CommName_CPS
    we   ds   123   Degree   123-Degree
    Se   dd   345   arrow    345-arrow 
    KM   sd   674   inv      674-inv
```

I have a table2

```
  PreA  BaB   CPS  CommName CommName_CPS
    we   ds   123   Degree   123-Degree
    Se   dd   345   arrow    345-arrow 
    KM   sd   674   inv      674-inv
    DJ   gfd  435   klm      435-klm
    rt   ggsd 865   hff      865-hff
```

Table1 (is a query table which is from another table) has field CommName_CPS which is concate two fields,same with table2.
I'm  trying to sort out uncommon data when compare tbl1 with tbl2 by using below query

```
SELECT table1.PreA, table1.BaB,table1.CPS,table1.CommName,table1.CommName_CPS
FROM table1
WHERE CommName_CPS Not In (select CommName_CPS from table2);
```

I get an error Invalid argument to function.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your syntax - and you're not using a function in that SQL, so it's most likely caused by your concatentate function that you're not showing us in your misnamed query Table1. As Serge suggests, there will be a problem if your syntax doesn't use the NZ function to append two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, not exists will be better to use if CommName_CPS could be null, you can read more about it in this article http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table2 t2
                   WHERE  t1.CommName_CPS = t2.CommName_CPS)
```

Comment: Query seems to work for tables , not on query tables. Don't know why

Comment: What is a `query table`? If it's actually a query on a table please show your SQL. That's what's causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments..

Change your Table 1 query to trap for null values when you concatenate the two fields:

```
SELECT PreA, BaB, CPS,CommName,  
NZ([CPS],"") & "-" & NZ([CommName],"") AS CommName_CPS From <YourOtherTable>
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't worked . It is surprised me that if i make table1 and table2(query tables) as normal tables and do concate and query uncommon data , it works. and no error. Really don't know why

Comment: Show your SQL that doesn't work - explain what is `uncommon data` and what a `query table` is.

Comment: Table1 and table2 in my question are query tables, from two of them i'm trying to sort uncommon data based on concatenate fields CommName_CPS  by SQL(its is in the question) . It's giving me Invalid argument to function error. your code worked in fetching Table1 and table2. but when i'm trying to sort uncommon data b/w them it is still giving error. And the query is Just **select * from maintbl where PreA is not null **

Comment: This is still very confusing - again - What is a "query table"? If you mean a `query ... on a table` then show your query SQL. How are you trying to `sort uncommon data`?

Comment: Are you talking about the Excel QueryTable object? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174288(v=office.11).aspx - you make no reference to Excel

Comment: Yes query on table. It is simple sql  `select * from maintbl where PreA is not null` .That make table1